# Issues with install shark tool via cmdbuild

Tags: postgresql, cmdb

Please help me, i'm new on cmdbuild and try to investigate this tools. But i stuck on the running of Shark.

I got the next errors in log :

shark.log:

```
2015-12-23 10:35:01,875: SharkEngineManager -> Working with 'org.enhydra.shark.CallbackUtil' implementation of core CallbackUtilities API

2015-12-23 10:35:01,875: SharkEngineManager -> Working with 'org.enhydra.shark.SharkObjectFactoryExt' implementation of core SharkObjectFactory API

2015-12-23 10:35:01,875: SharkEngineManager -> Working with 'org.enhydra.shark.StandardToolActivityHandler' implementation of core ToolAgentManager API

2015-12-23 10:35:01,875: SharkEngineManager -> Working with 'org.enhydra.shark.logging.StandardLoggingManager' implementation of Logging API

2015-12-23 10:35:02,441: StandardAssignmentManager -> Working with 'org.enhydra.shark.usergroup.DODSUserGroupManagerAdmin' implementation of UserGroup API

2015-12-23 10:35:02,517: StandardAssignmentManager -> Working with 'org.enhydra.shark.partmappersistence.DODSParticipantMappingAdmin' implementation of ParticipantMapping API

2015-12-23 10:35:02,517: SharkEngineManager -> Working with 'org.enhydra.shark.assignment.StandardAssignmentManager' implementation of Assignment API

2015-12-23 10:35:02,522: Process Cache configured - max. size is 100

2015-12-23 10:35:02,522: Resource Cache configured - max. size is 100

2015-12-23 10:35:02,522: SharkEngineManager -> Working with 'org.enhydra.shark.caching.LRUCacheMgr' implementation of Caching API

2015-12-23 10:35:02,676:  <SqlQueryExecute><SqlQueryException>(<Replicated>:ERROR: relation "shkprocessstates" does not exist

  Position: 32)

2015-12-23 10:35:02,684:  <SqlQueryExecute><SqlQueryException>(<Replicated>:ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block)

2015-12-23 10:35:02,687: DODSPersistentManager -> persisting String variables into BLOB for sizes greater than 4000

2015-12-23 10:35:02,687: SharkEngineManager -> Working with 'org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.DODSSelectivePersistenceManager' implementation of InstancePersistence API

2015-12-23 10:35:02,702: DODSGlobalPersistenceManager -> persisting String data into BLOB for sizes greater than 4000

2015-12-23 10:35:02,702: SharkEngineManager -> Working with 'org.enhydra.shark.globalpersistence.DODSGlobalPersistenceManager' implementation of GlobalPersistence API

2015-12-23 10:35:04,656: SharkEngineManager -> Working with 'org.cmdbuild.workflow.CMDBuildEventAuditManager' implementation of EventAudit API

2015-12-23 10:35:04,727: SharkEngineManager -> Working with 'org.enhydra.shark.repositorypersistence.DODSRepositoryPersistenceManager' implementation of RepositoryPersistence API

2015-12-23 10:35:04,730: SharkEngineManager -> Working with 'org.enhydra.shark.scripting.StandardScriptingManager' implementation of Scripting API

2015-12-23 10:35:04,731: SharkEngineManager -> Working without Security API implementation - SecurityManager is not specified.

2015-12-23 10:35:04,851: StandardToolAgentManager -> Working with 'org.enhydra.shark.appmappersistence.DODSApplicationMappingAdmin' implementation of ApplicationMapPersistence API

2015-12-23 10:35:04,851: SharkEngineManager -> Working with 'org.enhydra.shark.toolagent.StandardToolAgentManager' implementation of ToolAgentManager API

2015-12-23 10:35:04,851: SharkEngineManager -> Working without wfEngineInteroperability API implementation - WfEngineInteroperability implementation is not specified.

2015-12-23 10:35:04,862: SharkUtilities -> synchronizing XPDL cache

2015-12-23 10:35:04,878:  <SqlQueryExecute><SqlQueryException>(<Replicated>:ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block)

2015-12-23 10:35:04,878: Problem while initializing caches !!!
```

There is my catalina.out :

```
Shark will be configured from file /var/www/apache-tomcat-7.0.67/webapps/cmdbuild-shark-server-2.3.4/conf/Shark.conf
environmentType= tomcat
    t= org.objectweb.jotm.Current@41e7458a
        pre configure . . . . . .

Together Workflow Server 4.4-1

SharkEngineManager -> Shark engine is being initialized ...
com.lutris.dods.builder.generator.query.DataObjectException: Unknown SQLException: <SqlQueryExecute><SqlQueryException>(<Replicated>:ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.data.ProcessStateQuery._runQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.data.ProcessStateQuery.runQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.data.ProcessStateQuery.getNextDO(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.data.ProcessStateDO.__refreshCache(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.data.ProcessStateDO.refreshCache(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.DODSPersistentManager.refreshDOCaches(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.DODSPersistentManager.setLDBName(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.DODSPersistentManager.configure(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.DODSSelectivePersistenceManager.configure(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.SharkEngineManager.init(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.SharkEngineManager.init(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.SharkEngineManager.configure(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.enhydra.shark.Shark._conf(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.Shark.configure(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.servlet.SharkInitServlet.init(SharkInitServlet.java:121)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5327)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5617)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1095)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1957)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: <SqlQueryExecute><SqlQueryException>(<Replicated>:ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block)
        at com.lutris.dods.builder.generator.query.QueryBuilder.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.data.ProcessStateQuery.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at com.lutris.appserver.server.sql.standard.StandardDBQuery.query(Unknown Source)
        ... 36 more
*** Caused by:
java.sql.SQLException: <SqlQueryExecute><SqlQueryException>(<Replicated>:ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block)
        at com.lutris.dods.builder.generator.query.QueryBuilder.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.data.ProcessStateQuery.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at com.lutris.appserver.server.sql.standard.StandardDBQuery.query(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.data.ProcessStateQuery._runQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.data.ProcessStateQuery.runQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.data.ProcessStateQuery.getNextDO(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.data.ProcessStateDO.__refreshCache(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.data.ProcessStateDO.refreshCache(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.DODSPersistentManager.refreshDOCaches(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.DODSPersistentManager.setLDBName(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.DODSPersistentManager.configure(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.DODSSelectivePersistenceManager.configure(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.SharkEngineManager.init(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.SharkEngineManager.init(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.SharkEngineManager.configure(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.enhydra.shark.Shark._conf(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.Shark.configure(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.servlet.SharkInitServlet.init(SharkInitServlet.java:121)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5327)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5617)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1095)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1957)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
*** Caused by:
java.sql.SQLException: <SqlQueryExecute><SqlQueryException>(<Replicated>:ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block)
        at com.lutris.dods.builder.generator.query.QueryBuilder.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.data.ProcessStateQuery.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at com.lutris.appserver.server.sql.standard.StandardDBQuery.query(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.data.ProcessStateQuery._runQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.data.ProcessStateQuery.runQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.data.ProcessStateQuery.getNextDO(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.data.ProcessStateDO.__refreshCache(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.data.ProcessStateDO.refreshCache(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.DODSPersistentManager.refreshDOCaches(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.DODSPersistentManager.setLDBName(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.DODSPersistentManager.configure(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.instancepersistence.DODSSelectivePersistenceManager.configure(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.SharkEngineManager.init(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.SharkEngineManager.init(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.SharkEngineManager.configure(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.enhydra.shark.Shark._conf(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.Shark.configure(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.servlet.SharkInitServlet.init(SharkInitServlet.java:121)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5327)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5617)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1095)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1957)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
com.lutris.dods.builder.generator.query.DataObjectException: Unknown SQLException: <SqlQueryExecute><SqlQueryException>(<Replicated>:ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block)
        at org.enhydra.shark.repositorypersistence.data.XPDLQuery._runQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.repositorypersistence.data.XPDLQuery.runQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.repositorypersistence.data.XPDLQuery.getDOArray(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.repositorypersistence.DODSRepositoryPersistenceManager.getAllXPDLs(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.repositorypersistence.DODSRepositoryPersistenceManager.getExistingXPDLIds(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.SharkUtilities.synchronizeXPDLCache(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.SharkUtilities.restorePackages(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.SharkEngineManager.initCaches(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.SharkEngineManager.init(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.SharkEngineManager.configure(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.enhydra.shark.Shark._conf(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.Shark.configure(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.servlet.SharkInitServlet.init(SharkInitServlet.java:121)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5327)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5617)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1095)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1957)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: <SqlQueryExecute><SqlQueryException>(<Replicated>:ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block)
        at com.lutris.dods.builder.generator.query.QueryBuilder.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.repositorypersistence.data.XPDLQuery.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at com.lutris.appserver.server.sql.standard.StandardDBQuery.query(Unknown Source)
        ... 34 more
*** Caused by:
java.sql.SQLException: <SqlQueryExecute><SqlQueryException>(<Replicated>:ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block)
        at com.lutris.dods.builder.generator.query.QueryBuilder.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.repositorypersistence.data.XPDLQuery.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at com.lutris.appserver.server.sql.standard.StandardDBQuery.query(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.repositorypersistence.data.XPDLQuery._runQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.repositorypersistence.data.XPDLQuery.runQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.repositorypersistence.data.XPDLQuery.getDOArray(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.repositorypersistence.DODSRepositoryPersistenceManager.getAllXPDLs(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.repositorypersistence.DODSRepositoryPersistenceManager.getExistingXPDLIds(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.SharkUtilities.synchronizeXPDLCache(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.SharkUtilities.restorePackages(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.SharkEngineManager.initCaches(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.SharkEngineManager.init(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.SharkEngineManager.configure(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.enhydra.shark.Shark._conf(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.Shark.configure(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.servlet.SharkInitServlet.init(SharkInitServlet.java:121)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5327)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5617)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1095)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1957)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
org.enhydra.shark.api.internal.repositorypersistence.RepositoryException: Unknown SQLException: <SqlQueryExecute><SqlQueryException>(<Replicated>:ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block)
        at org.enhydra.shark.repositorypersistence.DODSRepositoryPersistenceManager.getExistingXPDLIds(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.SharkUtilities.synchronizeXPDLCache(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.SharkUtilities.restorePackages(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.SharkEngineManager.initCaches(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.SharkEngineManager.init(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.SharkEngineManager.configure(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.enhydra.shark.Shark._conf(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.Shark.configure(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.servlet.SharkInitServlet.init(SharkInitServlet.java:121)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5327)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5617)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1095)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1957)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.lutris.dods.builder.generator.query.DataObjectException: Unknown SQLException: <SqlQueryExecute><SqlQueryException>(<Replicated>:ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block)
        at org.enhydra.shark.repositorypersistence.data.XPDLQuery._runQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.repositorypersistence.data.XPDLQuery.runQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.repositorypersistence.data.XPDLQuery.getDOArray(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.repositorypersistence.DODSRepositoryPersistenceManager.getAllXPDLs(Unknown Source)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: <SqlQueryExecute><SqlQueryException>(<Replicated>:ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block)
        at com.lutris.dods.builder.generator.query.QueryBuilder.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.enhydra.shark.repositorypersistence.data.XPDLQuery.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at com.lutris.appserver.server.sql.standard.StandardDBQuery.query(Unknown Source)
        ... 34 more
Shark -> shark engine initialization is finished, it lasted 3 [s]
Shark -> Shark ready and waiting ...
        pre getConnection . . . . . .
        pre commit . . . . . .
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ init - end

And sure my configs :
```

Shark.conf:

```
org.cmdbuild.ws.url=http://localhost:8080/cmdbuild/
org.cmdbuild.ws.username=workflow
org.cmdbuild.ws.password=cmdbuild
```

auth.conf:

```
auth.methods=DBAuthenticator
serviceuser.prigileged=workflow
```

Please help to understand, what i do wrong? Or what more information need to give?
P.S. All users and grants are setted like needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that tomcat is started as root. CMDBuild itself does not need root privileges to run but shark does. 
In TOMCAT_HOME/cmdbuild/webapps/shark/META-INF/context.xml you should set your actual db name.